# tick interval is not working while applying tick interval its showing x and y both values

Tags: highcharts

i want to show each day date , but im getting alternative dates ,like 
1 feb and 3 feb and 5 feb i need full date like below without missing any dates n y axis.tried tickinterval 1 but its showing x and y values both.

> 1-feb-2020
>
> 2-feb-2020

[image: graph]

```
                        xAxis: {
                        tick,
                        type:'datetime',
                        dataLabels: {
                            align: 'right',
                            rotation: 45,
                            shape: null
                        }

                    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `tickInterval` to one day and use the `formatter` function:

```
xAxis: {
  ...,
  tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e-%b-%Y', this.value);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4815/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Answer (score 1):

Setting the xAxis to the under config is a solution which you are looking for:

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%e-%b-%Y'
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qmro0was/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval